# Highcharts- this.category returns undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In highcharts on clicking any point or bar I want an alert giving the X axis value ... I'm using dotnet.highcharts in Visual Studio
I tried the following

```
public partial class regression
{
    DataSet dsSeries = new DataSet();
    ArrayList totalCount , failCount,passCount ,Week = new ArrayList();
    object[] totalValues, passValues, failValues;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Report();
    }

    public DataSet BindData()
    {
        String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxxxxxxConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT `Week`,`total`,`PassCount`,`FailCount` FROM Regression";
        command.Connection = connection;

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void Report()
    {
        dsSeries = BindData();

        if (dsSeries == null) return;

        foreach (DataRow ww in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Week.Add(ww["Week"]);
        }

        foreach (DataRow tot in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            totalCount.Add(Convert.ToInt32(tot["total"]));
            totalValues = totalCount.ToArray(typeof(object)) as object[];
        }

        foreach (DataRow pass in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            passCount.Add(Convert.ToInt32(pass["PassCount"]));
            passValues = passCount.ToArray(typeof(object)) as object[];
        }

        foreach (DataRow fail in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            failCount.Add(Convert.ToInt32(fail["FailCount"]));
            failValues = failCount.ToArray(typeof(object)) as object[];
        }

        hcline.Title = new Title ("Report");            
        hcline.YAxis.Add(new YAxisItem { title = new Title("Number of Tests") });
        hcline.XAxis.Add(new XAxisItem { title= new Title("Week"), categories = Week.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[] });

        var series = new Collection<Serie>();
        series.Add(new Serie { name = "Pass", data = passValues });
        series.Add(new Serie { name = "Fail", data = failValues });

        hcline.PlotOptions = new PlotOptionsLine { dataLabels = new DataLabels { enabled = true } };
        hcline.PlotOptions.events = new Highchart.Core.Events.PlotOptionEvents { click = "alert('hi :'+ this.category)" };

        //customize tooltip

        hcline.Tooltip = new ToolTip("'WW'+this.x +': '+ this.y");

        //bind to controls
        hcline.DataSource = series;
        hcline.DataBind();


    }
}
```

The value that is returned is **undefined** 
I also tried

```
this.x
event.point.x
```

this.x returns **undefined** and event.point.x returns the **index** of the category.
But the **this.x** in tooltip works properly.

How to achieve the value of the category?

pls help!!

Comment: please check this example http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/8mSJC/. I'm getting the category value correctly.

Comment: @strikers tried but still I get undefined

Comment: can you show the issue working in a js fiddle

Comment: I'm integrating result from MySql to bind the data for Highchart. So I don't think I can show in js fiddle.. But I can post the entire code.

Comment: Could you attach generated code by your wrapper? I mean JS code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `event.point.category` to get the value of the category

Comment: Here's a live working example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/16h4qwme/